# How to extract the number and only one string after the number using python?

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string with this pattern `test_str = "Abc xyz another_name 123 V aaa"`. I need to extract the the number and the string after the number afterwards, as value and its unit. How can I do that?
I can only get the number using regex but can not the string after it which is the unit.

`re.findall(r'[0-9]+', test_str)`

the extected output is : `123 V`

Edit:

Additioanly: some of the units may contains Slash or Back slash or numbers with comma, how can I get those as well ? 
Which means some of them could be `1.2` or `1,1` and for the units `A/C` or`DC-W` etc

Comment: why not split the string on spaces, then index the number and string accordingly from the list?

Comment: I need to add the space inbetween and with re would be easier to find other patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. This regex will return numbers followed by a space and a string.

```
re.findall(r'[1-9]+ [a-zA-Z-\/]+', test_str)
```

Comment: Thanks yes thats work. additional question : what would be the pattern for strings which can also include `/` or`-`

Answer (score 1):

This pattern match numbers with `,` or `.`, end with unit with `/` or `-`, 
 and any blanks between them.

```
re.findall(r'[0-9,\.]+\s*[a-zA-Z/\-]*', test_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include also any other characters for a string including `/`, `-`, or numbers,
I think any character other than whitespace would work.

```py
re.findall(r'[0-9]+ [^\s]+', test_str)
```